# Exception to ValueError:

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I'm trying to make dataframe AND csv file of multiple lists:

But the issue is not all lists have same number of arrays.

And "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions" is always raised.

Is there anyway to bypass this error?

Here is my code:

```
keyword_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'NaverID':NaverID,
                                  'Neighbor#':final_neighbor_total,
                                  'Today's Visitor':final_today_total,
                                  'Total Visitor':final_visit_total})
keyword_dataframe = keyword_dataframe.sort_values('Total Visitor', ascending=False)
keyword_dataframe.index = np.arange(1,len(keyword_dataframe)+1)

keyword_dataframe.to_csv('NaverBlogRanking_RESULT.csv', index=False)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What are the contents of the Keys you are using in the dictionary (NaverID, final_neighbor_total final)visit_total)? Are the contents of the keys 2D arrays? Please elaborate and edit your question so we can understand the problem better.

Comment: List of strings. Nothing sophisticated.

Comment: This error is occurring due to varying shapes of your lists. Check the shape of the lists, and try to reshape them. Also, you are trying to use sort_values to sort strings?   Anyhow, I would suggest you to possibly broadcast the lists to make them of same dimensions, not sure if this would work but you could try.

Comment: Here's one problem `'Today's Visitor'`

Comment: The original column name was in Korean, so I edited for convenience. Do not mind name of columns.